# label, прозрачный фон

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

У меня есть несколько пар PictureBox над котором стоит label и button. Мне нужно сделать чтобы фон label был прозрачным. Написав кусок кода, у меня в первой паре label налезает на button. Во второй и третьей label просто нет :/

```
        label10.Parent = pictureBoxEx1;
        label10.BackColor = Color.Transparent;

        label11.Parent = pictureBoxEx2;
        label11.BackColor = Color.Transparent;

        label12.Parent = pictureBoxEx3;
        label12.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
```

Добавив одну строку, только для первой пары всё заработало, для двух других вообще элементы пропали

```
        label10.Parent = pictureBoxEx1;
        button19.Parent = pictureBoxEx1;
        label10.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
```

Comment: Покажите, как вы создаете контролы.

Comment: Возможно, дело в z-ордере. Попробуйте методы [BringToFront](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.bringtofront), [SendToBack](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.sendtoback).